# Changing EventSouce event name not working in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, server-sent-events

i have an `asp.net mvc` application with `knockout.js`

i'm using `HTML5 EventSource` for push messages

c#

```
 private static void UpdateOnlineUsers()
    {
        var ou = Clients.Select(c => new { UserName = c.User.Name, Time = c.DateTime.ToString("G") }).ToList();
        Clients.ForEach(c =>
        {
            c.Stream.WriteLine("data:" + new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ou) + "\n\n");
        });
    }
```

and javascript is

```
eventSource.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
        if (e.data.length) {
            var json = JSON.parse(e.data);
            if (json.Text) {
                messages.push(json);
            }
            else onlineUsers(json);
        }
    }, false);
```

which is **working** fine.

but i want to add a specific name for the event so i added new line in c# method like

```
Clients.ForEach(c =>
        {
            c.Stream.WriteLine("event: messenger \n");  // added new
            c.Stream.WriteLine("data:" + new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ou) + "\n\n");
        });
```

and changed script to

```
eventSource.addEventListener('messenger',...`
```

and it **stopped working** after adding event name

Please help!.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like it works if you remove the space between the event name and "\n", like so:

```
 Clients.ForEach(c =>
    {
        c.Stream.WriteLine("event: messenger\n");  // added new w/o space
        c.Stream.WriteLine("data:" + new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ou) + "\n\n");
    });
```

Comment: good catch.. i ended up adding `client.Stream.WriteLine("event:messenger\ndata:" + new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ou) + "\n");` which is working. Thank you.